# d3 path is being drawn twice while attempting path tween

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tween

I am using this technique to tween a path in d3:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5649592

I am animating arcs between nodes. My data looks like this:

```
this.transfers = [[1, 480, 0, 5], [2, 0, 480, 20], [3, 0, 720, 5], [3, 240, 720, 5], [3, 480, 720, 5], [5, 480, 0, 5]];
```

The goal of the code is to visualize gameplay. The first element of each inner array above is the round of the game, the next two are the x coordinates of nodes that transferred some points -- the first node arching to the second -- and the fourth is the number of points that were transferred. I am trying to program an arc to tween between the nodes that took part in the transfer, with the arc sweeping from one node to the other. This is the code for the tweened arc:

```
this.linkAnimation = this.svg.append('g')
  .selectAll('path')
  .data (self.transfers)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('fill', 'none');

this.timedAnimation();

timedAnimation( ) {
  for (let j = 0; j < this.rounds+1; j++ ) {

    this.linkAnimation = this.linkAnimation
      .transition()              // transition for delay between rounds
      .delay(2000)
      .attr('d', (t, i) => {
        if (j == t[0]) {
          let denominator = (t[1] < t[2])? 1.75 : 2; // to keep forward and reverse arcs from tracing the same path
          return ['M', t[1], self.height, 'A',
            (t[1] - t[2])/2, ',',
            (t[1] - t[2])/denominator, 0, 0, ',',
            t[1] < t[2] ? 1 : 0, t[2], ',', self.height]
            .join(' ');
        }
      })
    .attr('stroke-width', d => this.linkWidth(d[3]))
    .call(this.transition);
  }
}

transition(path) {
  path.transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", self.tweenDash);
}

tweenDash(path) {
  let l = this.getTotalLength(),
    i = d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l);
  if (l == 0) { return; } else {
    return function(t) { return i(t); };
}
```

The issue is that each arc is drawing twice consecutively. It is fully drawn (not tweened) once right before the tweened arc appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the start of the animation you have to initialize the `stroke-dasharray`.

Choose a really big size for the initial dash, bigger then any of the path lengths you are going to draw.

```
.attr('stroke-width', d => this.linkWidth(d[3]))
.attr('stroke-dasharray', "0,1000000")
.call(this.transition);
```

Comment: Can you explain what was happening? Before adding the code you suggested, the code was drawing one arc (not tweened) and then drawing the same arc tweened directly after that.

Comment: look for the docs of `stroke-dasharray` and slow the animation down (long duration) and see what happens with and without this line.